# How many arrangements do we have?

Tags: combinatorics

We have $N$ boxes and an inexhaustible supply of objects belonging to $k$ distinct classes such that $N\gt k$.

How many different arrangements of the objects in the boxes are there if

(a) each of the boxes may contain only one single object,
(b) every class is represented?

**I have already tried** to argue like this:
In order for the classes to be represented we have $k!$ choices in the case of the first $k$ boxes. Then I thought that for the rest ($N-k$) boxes we have $(N-k)^k$ possibilities. My first answer was: $k!(N-k)^k$. Then I enumerated the possibilities in the case of $N=4$ and $k=2$ and it turned out that my solution gave twice as many arrangements than I could enumerate. Then I got stuck.

Comment: What have you tried?  Please include any work you have done on the problem so that we can write a response that is appropriate to your skill level.

Comment: Voting down a question (if it makes sense) is unjust. Reason: A question voted down will attract less visitors. Who will then solve my problem that I still consider tough. I don' even know if anybody will read this complaint  :(

Comment: Are conditions a) and b) together or is it separate.  a) each of the boxes contain just any one single object. b) each of the boxes contain atleast one object of each class?

Comment: Together: both conditions have to be met!

Comment: for $N=4, k=2$ I have 14 arrangements, which is more than $k!(N-k)^k$. What did you get? I am assuming the boxes are labelled or ordered ("distinguishable").

Comment: Yes, the boxes are "distinguishable." I forgot what I got... It was late in the nite. I gave up working on the problem because of being very tired.

Comment: zoli, was there anything about my solution that you need explained further?

Comment: I am OK, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without condition (b), the solution is straightforward - number of arrangements $A=k^N$

Condition b) implies we should remove the arrangements with only $k-1$ classes represented - there are ${k \choose k-1}$ way to choose which classes,  and for a given choice there are ${k-1}^N$ arrangements.

But wait! that has double counted cases where there are only $k-2$ classes. So we have to add them back in; and that affects the count for only $k-3$ classes, and so on.

Finally we run down through the possibilities on [inclusions and exclusions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) and get:
$$\begin{align}A&=k^N-{k\choose k-1}(k-1)^N+{k\choose k-2}(k-2)^N-{k\choose k-3}(k-3)^N+...\\
&=\sum_0^{k-1}(-1)^i{k\choose k-i}(k-i)^N
\end{align}$$

Quick test: for $N=4, k=2$, $$A= {2\choose2}2^4 - {2\choose 1}1^4 = 1\times 16 - 2\times 2 = 14$$

Comment: I would have really liked the combination formulas to be ${k\choose i}$ in all places than ${k\choose(k-i}$.  Nice one!

Comment: @satishramanathan sure, that works too of course, but I preferred to keep it in line with the explanation.

Comment: You got it. I just did upvote. Looking forward to working with you at this site.

Answer (score 1):

The [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) $S(N,k)$ count the number of ways to partition $N$ distinguishable objects into $k$ nonempty blocks. Multiply $S(n,k)$ by $k!$ to assign individual colors to these blocks, and you have the number you are after: It is the number of surjective maps $f: \>[N]\to[k]$.